# Function containing a for loop stops running after click event

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, dom

I am trying to make a shopping list app that requires the following -

add items to list based on user input, and include a delete button.

toggle items being crossed off with a line through style.

remove items from list when delete button is clicked in corresponding li.

```
enter code here
```

The issue I am running into, is that I cannot cross off old list items after new list items are added.

I created a function that is a for loop to loop through the list and toggle the .done  class on and off. it works to allow me to toggle line through on and off but as soon as a new item is added to the list through click or key press event, the function stops working.

I figured by placing the toggleDone(); inside of the functions  inside of the click and keypress functions as well as globally, it would work on both newly added list items and the original list items.

what actually happens is if i click to add a new item to the list, it no longer functions on the original list items, and then if i keypress to add an item to the list, the function works on the old list items as well as the keypress items, but not the click items.

```
const input = document.getElementById("userInput");
const btn = document.getElementById("enter");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");

const list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");



function toggleDone(){
    for (let i=0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            list[i].classList.toggle("done");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
 if (inputLength() > 0) { 
 createListElement(); 
 

 
 
} 
toggleDone();
})

this is my click event

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could simplify things by using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) technique. Attach a click event handler to the `ul` element instead of each individual `li` - this works because events propagate upward (aka bubbling). You can inspect the `event.target` passed to the callback function to see exactly what was clicked.

Here is an example demonstrating how to toggle a style on `li` elements using event delegation:

```js
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle("done");
});
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Apologies for my poor question details. I'm very new to coding and find it hard to put this stuff to words. I appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

1. You might not be calling the function in the right place
2. You should add if else statement when calling for loop
3. For the for loop don't say "let" (depends on version) say "var"

This link might help (example)

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp